# Strange variable passed to function? time.Minute not being passed as a minute

Tags: go

I have a function that is

```
func myFunc(mycontext context.Context, duration time.Duration, f someFunc) {
for {
   select {
      case <- time.After(duration):
          // do some stuff
      case <-mycontext.Done():
          // Other stuff
   }
}
```

This is called with

```
duration := time.Minute
go myFunc(mycontext, duration, myFuncPointer)
```

Today I noticed this function never exits. Upon pausing and inspecting the gothread I see that my duration variable has this value

```
github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4.DefaultMaxInterval (60000000000)
```

Why does it have this value and not my one minute duration? Also duration never gets reassigned at any point so I don't think its that.

Comment: Why would it exit? Unless the stuff you left out includes `return`...

Answer (score 3):

> I see that my duration variable has this value
>
> ```
> github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4.DefaultMaxInterval (60000000000)
> ```
>
> Why does it have this value and not my one minute duration?

---

Read the Go standard library [package time](https://pkg.go.dev/time) documentation.

> ```
> type Duration int64
> ```
>
> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count.

> ```
> const (
>     Nanosecond  Duration = 1
>     Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
>     Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
>     Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
>     Minute               = 60 * Second
>     Hour                 = 60 * Minute
> )
> ```

---

`time.Minute` is `60000000000` nanoseconds.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(int64(time.Minute))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/YVx4ddJYnv6

```
60000000000
```

Comment: Hell of a lot of upvotes for something that doesn't answer my question at all. Why does the debugger show my variable type changing. If I copy the code you have exactly and run the debugger the type is Minute (60000000000), which is different than what I asked

Comment: @Kilbo Minute isn't a type.

Comment: @Kilbo: You are not making sense. `time.Minute` is a constant of type `time.Duration` and value  `60000000000`: https://go.dev/play/p/EKsUzr54fwg.

Comment: Right but the type should be time.Duration, VSCode showed the type as github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4.DefaultMaxInterval

Comment: @Kilbo: "VSCode showed the type as github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4.DefaultMaxInterval." You are not making sense. DefaultMaxInterval is a constant value, not a type. `DefaultMaxInterval` is defined in `github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4` `exponential.go` as `const DefaultMaxInterval = 60 * time.Second`. For example, https://go.dev/play/p/ptzePzu32-i: `DefaultMaxInterval: Type time.Duration Value 60000000000` where `time.Second: Type time.Duration Value 1000000000`.